# How do I make a reference to a table column from the parent query within the subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say a have a table called people with the following columns:

1. person_id
2. name
3. parent_person_id

I'm trying to write a query to return the following:

1. person.person_id as 'id'
2. person.name as 'name'
3. person.parent_person_id as 'parent id'
4. person.label (person.person_id = person.person_parent_id from parent query) as 'parent name'.

I'm having difficult with the item number 4 subquery.

My question is:

How do I make a reference to the person.person_parent_id from the parent query from within the subquery? I feel like on the code bellow if I could get people.parent_person_id value from the external query and use it on the inner one, I would achieve my goal.

```
SELECT
    people.person_id as 'Person ID',
    people.name as 'Person Name',
    people.parent_person_id as 'Parent ID',
    (
        SELECT
            people.name
        FROM
            people
        WHERE
            people.parent_person_id = people.person_id;
    ) as 'Parent Name'
FROM 
    people;
```

I could be wrong, and I'm definitely open minded. Please share your thoughts and help this good soul move on with his quest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite close.  You just need proper table aliases:

```
SELECT p.person_id as PersonID,
       p.name as PersonName,
       p.parent_person_id as ParentID,
       (SELECT parent.name
        FROM people parent
        WHERE p.parent_person_id = parent.person_id;
       ) as ParentName
FROM people p;
```

Notes:

- This would more normally be expressed as a `LEFT JOIN`, but the correlated subquery is also a very reasonable approach.
- Notice that the query is easier to follow with table aliases -- and you need them in this case.
- Don't get in the habit of using single quotes for column names.  This often causes confusion and can result in hard to find bugs.
- Your version doesn't work because in the condition `people.parent_person_id = people.person_id`, `people` refers to the inner `from`.  You need table aliases to distinguish between the inner and outer references to `people`.

Comment: The aliases did the trick. Thanks for the extend response. I can see how the  LEFT JOIN would save me some typing but I wonder if is there any  other benefits on using JOIN over subqueries?

Comment: @ViniciusSantana . . . In some databases, `join`s might offer more opportunities for optimization.  And, `join`s are more flexible, so they are more important to learn well.  But, there are some cases where correlated subqueries perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an alias for each table

```
SELECT
    p1.person_id as 'Person ID',
    p1.name as 'Person Name',
    p1.parent_person_id as 'Parent ID',
    (
        SELECT
            p2.name
        FROM
            people as p2
        WHERE
            p2.parent_person_id = p1.person_id;
    ) as 'Parent Name'
FROM 
    people as p1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use joins?

```
SELECT
p1.person_id as 'Person ID',
p1.name as 'Person Name',
p1.parent_person_id as 'Parent ID',
p2.name as 'Parent name'
FROM people p1
LEFT JOIN people p2 ON p1.parent_person_id = p2.person_id;
```

Comment: Is there any benefits on using joins instead of subqueries or is it just a matter of preferences? It seems to me like I would achieve the same result with both methods. Great to know my options though.

Comment: Of course. In your example maybe not, but imagine 10 or 20 tables from witch you need data. Nobody (including you) could understand what is happening in that querry. Also, if you need multiple values from your second table (for example you want to show parents parent) you get in a tricky situation with first option. From preformance standing, it depends from querry to querry, in your example subquerry can easily be better option but in more complex querrys offten is not. For me joins are way of easy querry writing and understanding in few months or years